# Junit Category symbol not found

Tags: junit

I can't get sample Junit 4.10 code with @Category annotation to compile.  Code is:

```
import org.junit.*;

@Category({CatA.class})
public class A {

@Test
public void a() {
  System.out.println("\n ***** Method a \n");
}

}
```

Command to compile code:

```
javac -cp .:junit-4.10.jar A.java

A.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
@Category({CatA.class})
 ^
  symbol: class Category
1 error
```

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 3):

You need the following import in your code as well:

```
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
```